# Using CSS viewport height and child absolute positioning creates fixed positioning?

Tags: html, css, position

#### Goal

I would like to position an element absolutely.

#### Issues

Oddly, said element somehow appears as if it were `position: fixed`. Weird!

```
    html, body {
        height:100%;
    }
    .absolute {
        position:absolute;
    }
```

This creates an element that acts like it is fixed on the page.

This is very puzzling and inconvenient. Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2n6tsyzk/8/).

#### Help

Is there a way that I can add absolute positioning to this element without changing `html` and `body` height?

One last thing to note: In my case, the content inside the body overflows window height, if that's important...

Thank you for your help!

**edit:** Changed title slightly, removed unneeded interjections.

Answer (score 6):

First let's understand how `position:absolute` works.

`absolute` position removes an element from the normal flow of the document and places it relative to the first parent that has `relative` positioning.

The default value of position property is `static`. So the class `.absolute` has no parent that is `relatively` positioned. Therefore it stays relative to the viewport and appears all the time even when you scroll.

So set a parent element of `.absolute` to `relative` positioning and you will get the desired result. Here, you can set the `.element` to `relative` positioning.

```
.element{
   width:100%;
   height:2000px;
   position:relative;
}
```

You can open the fiddle below and scroll to see the desired effect.

Fiddle - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2n6tsyzk/8/)

Answer (score 0):

by default position absolute is relative to the body beacause the absolute element is out of the  elements flow. So if you want your absolute element to be abble "to understand" the other elements and be abble to move width parent, it's parent should be in relative position.

regardless to your JSFiddle put a position relative to .element the .baby should be abble to move with it parent

```
.element {
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: i think Aravind Bharathy has explain before me

Comment: but m not commenting under the Aravind's answer. Please try to understand. if new user will read your answer, how they will get it? hope you will get my point. Sorry if my words hurt you.

Comment: no trouble, by default position absolute is relative to the body beacause the absolute element is out of the  elements flow. So if you want your absolute element to be abble "to understand" the other elements and be abble to move width parent, it's parent should be in relative position. I expect i'm clear my english is a bit poor

Comment: Hey, i think you did not get me. M saying describle this in  your answer so edit your answer and type there so it will be useful for users who will read your answer. Thanx :)